# How to recover a banned Runescape account?

Tags: runescape

I sporadically play Runescape, I can barely call it playing since I log in, check my bank, equip my character and then get bored of the combat system. This has been going on for a few years.

Tonight I tried to log in because due to the  release of Darkscape and found out I was banned for Macroing. After [researching](https://runescape.wiki/w/Macro) a bit I found out what  'Macroing' is. The ban was issued at the 5th of this month.

The problem comes with that I wasn't even online this month, nor do I use any sort of software to cheat ( Frankly, it would take more time to get a bot to work than I've been online this year).

I read a bit on their website, and it says that I'm not allowed to appeal the ban, however, it's clear to me that my account wasn't used by me, and thus the ban is completly unfair. Is there any way (and if so, how) to get in contact with an administrator?

---

**Update:** I managed to recover my runescape account by contacting Runescape Support via (a rather hidden) support ticket mechanism. Turns out my account got compromised on a wave of account thefts in 2013/14.

Comment: If you didn't use your account, who did? Did you give the password to someone?

Comment: Evidently not. If that was the case, I would've known it was banned in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to contact Jagex on Twitter [@JagexSupport](https://twitter.com/JagexSupport). However, keep in mind there is a low chance of recovering your account, especially since your account was banned for macroing.

Did you have two-step authentication? If not, your account probably got hacked and was used for botting purposes. Then Jagex detected this and banned it.

Comment: I don't think I had. I registered the account during the 2007-2009 era (or very close to it), and I didn't once change any security settings other than PIN number. Thank you for your reply, I will try that. Have a good day/night